# Constructing cell complexes from homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to understand an exercise that states the following:

**Question**: Construct cell complexes with the given homology groups.
$$ H_0(K) = \mathbb{Z}\quad H_1(K) = \mathbb{Z}_3\quad H_2(K) = 0$$

I understand that $H_2(K) = 0$ implies that any 2-cycle in my complex has to be the boundary of some 3-chain. What is confusing me here is how $H_1(K) = \mathbb{Z}_3$ works. Does this mean that there is some 1-cycle, say $c$, such that $c + c + c$ is the boundary of some 2-chain? Or am I supposed to relate these to the cokernel of some $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map?

I haven't been able to find any promising resources after searching for a while, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the a 2-cell. Glue $(t,1-t,0)\sim (0,t,1-t) \sim (1-t,0,t)$.

Comment: I guess the identification you describe gives the skeleton of a tetrahedron, but I still do not immediately understand how $H_1$ would be $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: I don’t think I am describing something related to a tetrahedron. It is a triangle glueing all three edges to a single segment; something similar to the construction of a real projective plane, except for “glueing antipodal points on the boundary of a disk” is replaced by “glueing every 120 degree point triple on the boundary”.

Comment: This cell complex is pathwise connected, and has fundamental group $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ by Serfeit van-Kampen’s Theorem. Thus $H_0$ is $\mathbb Z$ and $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ (Hurewicz’s Theorem). If I am not wrong, you can also calculate them via, for example, CW complex theory.

Comment: Though you are considering 3-fold Dunce Cap, here is the Homology calculation of 5-fold Dunce cap: https://youtu.be/aTPi2unTIVQ

Comment: My mistake, I tried to visualize it without going through the definition. The identification makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: Look up Moore spaces (they are e.g. covered in Hatcher)! This is e.g. $M(\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}, 1)$.